# Show column depending on dropdown selection - not working

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

Depending on dropdown column selection,. I need one of 5 columns to show and hide the others, however the code does not seem to work, what am I doing wrong? I know I'm missing something.

```
  // Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"

$(document).ready(function(){



//Define which columns to show/hide by default

  $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();

  $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();

  $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();

  $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();

//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection  

$("select[title='BE Info 1']").change(function() {
  if ($("select[title='BE Info 1']").val() == "B1 Choices") { 
  $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').show();
  $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();

 }  if($("select[title='BE Info 1']").val() == "B2.5-3 Choices"){ 
  $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').show();
  $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  } 

 }  if($("select[title='BE Info 1']").val() == "B4 Choices""){ 
  $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').show();
  $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  } 

}  else if($("select[title='BE Info 1']").val() == "B5 Choices"){ 
  $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').show();
  } 


 });


});
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is actually being run? `$(document).ready()` doesn't usually work with SharePoint pages due to much of the content being loaded via AJAX requests. Try putting all the code inside a function (eg `onPageLoad()`), and running `_spOnBodyLoadFunctionNames.push("onPageLoad")` at the top of the page.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, as you see I am not very versed in JavaScript.
I'm not even sure how to make a function or onload I searched for answers and saw some code for SharePoint that only had 2 choices and tried to add 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of typos any decent JavaScript editor would have warned you about (and saved you loads of time)

Go checkout

- [VSCode (Visual Studio Code)](http://code.visualstudio.com/) - Microsoft - Free
- [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) - Adobe - Free

and use [JSHint.com](http://jshint.com/) - (available as plugin in both editors),
before you ask a question here and have to wait if someone is nice enough to answer

I pasted your code; it gives 52 warnings

Comment: Thank you Danny, that was the cup of joe I needed. Thank you. And a sincere thanks to Jonathan Holvey and jasonscript for taking the time to help.

Comment: Danny quick question please - when a different selection is made in a dropdown - ( perhaps for corrective reasons at users end ) how do you clear the values each time a different selection is made. I realized that if I select choice 1 and tick some checkboxes if I change my mind and select the second dropdown , the values from the 1st dropdown select are still checked.  I don't want that saved into the database just what they selected ultimately.

Comment: Sounds to me like a new question, because I can't match your requirement with the code you show

Answer (score 1):

Is this your actual code that you are using? I tried formatting this code and it looks like this code is invalid

Repeated Quotes Prematurely exiting `change` callback here

> ```
>     if($("select[title='BE Info 1']").val() == "B4 Choices"")  // <- repeated quotes
>     { 
>         $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
>         $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').hide();
>         $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').show();
>         $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
>     } 
>
> }  // <- this bracket is closing your 'change' callback
> ```

Cleaning it up a little looks like this:

```
// Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"

$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Define which columns to show/hide by default
    $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
    $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
    $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
    $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();

    //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection  
    $("select[title='BE Info 1']").change(function() 
    {
        // use jQuery to get the value of "BE Info 1"
        var selectedVal = $("select[title='BE Info 1']").val();

        if (selectedVal == "B1 Choices") 
        { 
            $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
        }  
        else if (selectedVal == "B2.5-3 Choices")
        { 
            $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
        }
        else if (selectedVal == "B4 Choices")
        { 
            $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').show();
            $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
        } 
        else if(selectedVal == "B5 Choices")
        { 
            $('nobr:contains("B1 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B2.5-3 Choices').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B4 Choices")').closest('tr').hide();
            $('nobr:contains("B5 Choices")').closest('tr').show();
        }
        else
        {
            /* selected Value doesn't match any of the above conditions
             * so nothing is going to happen
             */
        }
    });
});
```

See if these syntax-corrections work for you. When writing JavaScript it is really helpful to use a syntax highlighter like Notepad++ or Sublime, or anything really.

You should also see errors running your original code when looking at the Developer Tools in Chrome <kbd>F12</kbd> or Firefox.

Comment: Hello jasonscript. I am not much of coder but learning. What I did was found some code that was meant for 2 choices and tried to make it to 5 and it did not work. I must had missed something. Here is the link to that code http://bingggg.blogspot.com/2011/11/showhide-columns-based-on-drop-down.html

Comment: @MikeRooker I've made some minor changes to the `IF` block in my answer above. Please try this code. Note that you do need to include `jquery` to get everything to work